# Calculate two different sum with two different where in one query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Guys I have a query that will calculate a certain sum, same logic, same code, but with different where clause, Can I do this in one query? Example:

```
Select SUM( mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity) as order_sum from sometable where mi.myitem_order_id = 'somevalue';
```

2nd query:

```
Select SUM( mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity) as location_sum from sometable where mi.myitem_location_id = 'somevalue';
```

To make this clear, That first query will calculate all orders in different locations, while that 2nd query will calculate per location only. I need to get `order_sum` and `location_sum` simultaneously with different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it this way (with conditional aggregation)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN mi.myitem_order_id = 'somevalue' 
             THEN mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity END) order_sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mi.myitem_location_id = 'somevalue' 
             THEN mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity END) location_sum 
-- WHERE mi.myitem_order_id = 'somevalue'
--    OR mi.myitem_location_id = 'somevalue'
  FROM sometable
```

Comment: In your update to the question you're saying *calculate all orders in different locations* and yet you have `mi.myitem_order_id = 'some value'` condition in where clause..?

Comment: An order consists of more than one locations, each location will be grouped with their order_id, so yes,

Comment: I prefer this to other one.

Comment: OK, then you got your answer. Or are you getting unexpected results from proposed solution?

Comment: On a second thought `WHERE` conditions might be tricky in this one. In order to be sure I need to know more about schema and probably see sample data. Because of that I commented out WHERE clause. You might need to tweak it to properly accommodate for both sums. But approach still stands you do it with one query conditionally checking for necessary rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query like this also

```
SELECT (Select SUM( mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity) 
from sometable AS mi where mi.myitem_order_id = 'somevalue') as order_sum,
(Select SUM( mi.myitem_price * msi.my_item_quantity) 
from sometable AS mi where mi.myitem_location_id = 'somevalue') as location_sum
```